# SSIS Project Connections

Tags: ssis, bids

Using Visual Studio to build my SSIS packages. Project connections - they seem like a good idea so I'll do that instead of repeating my code....

Problem when you try to run the packages individually outside Visual Studio, say dtexec, they don't have any connection associated with them so they fail.

Do I really have to duplicate package connections for all 20 packages? Is there not a way to share a connection?

I want to be able to run each package separately/in groups as they will have a differing schedules.

I'm a developer so Visual Studio is my default goto - would SQL Server provide a better house for this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

For non-project based connections, when you run the package, it'd take a form like

```
dtexec /file MyPackage.dtsx
```

However, for project based connections, you need to include the project in the [dtexec](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh231187.aspx) call. Otherwise, you'll end up with missing connection errors

```
dtexec /package MyPackage.dtsx /project MyProject.ispac
```

Note: the current documentation is inaccurate as it specifies `/file MyPackage.dtsx /project MyProject.ispac` The /File parameter is invalid for Project deployment model solutions

Comment: you can't include a file and project parameter together like that... "The File option cannot be specified with the DTS, SQL, Server, Project, ISServer
, User, or Password options."