# SSIS project parameters can't be found when package deployed

Tags: visual-studio-2012, deployment, parameters, ssis

When I deploy package to test server, all parameters that are in project scope are not available. (they are all in project.params) file.

**Here is how we deploy and run packages?**
Prior SSIS 2012, I would have xxx.dtsx and xxx.dtsConfig in folder, then we would have script that uses DTEXEC tool to execute package. Our scheduling  tool runs jobs/script hourly, daily, monthly, etc...

Now, with SSIS 2012, they got away with configuration and introduced parameters. Now in my package deployment folder, I have only xxx.dtsx and project.params files. Project.params file contains all variables that I decided to parametrize. While this work nicely when debugging in VS2012, once deployed, it doesn't work at all.

Any advice on what to do here?

Thanks

Comment: Deploy to SSISDB, run as usual*. See also http://stackoverflow.com/a/31390253/181965

Comment: Thanks. That worked. My first try failed cause I used /file option instead of /package

Comment: If you post solution. I will accept it as an answer

Answer (score 1):

For non-project based connections, when you run the package, it'd take a form like

```
dtexec /file MyPackage.dtsx
```

However, for project based connections, you need to include the project (.ispac) in the [dtexec](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh231187.aspx) call. Otherwise, you'll end up with missing connection or project parameter errors

```
dtexec /package MyPackage.dtsx /project MyProject.ispac
```